# Same query but different plan on different server

Tags: sql-server, performance, azure-sql-database

I have recursive CTE query, it was taking 30s to execute, after investigation I found out that a column (`Name`) with datatype `nvarchar(MAX)` was the problem so I changed it to `nvarchar(1024)`. After which execution time reduced to 2s on DEV env. However, when I perform same alter on QA environment I don't see any improvement. Strange thing is that both servers are generating different execution plan, both server has same configuration, same schema. In fact DEV has more data.

Query:

```
WITH Ancestor (Id, TreeLevel, Branch, Name) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        I.Id, 0 AS TreeLevel, 
        CAST(I.Name AS VARCHAR(1024)) AS Branch, 
        I.Name
    FROM      
        dbo.Items AS I 
    WHERE   
        (I.Parent_Id IS NULL)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        D.Id, A.TreeLevel + 1 AS TreeLevel, 
        CAST(A.Branch + ' -> ' + CAST(D.Name AS VARCHAR(1024)) AS VARCHAR(1024)) AS Branch, 
        D.Name
    FROM     
        dbo.Items AS D 
    INNER JOIN
        Ancestor AS A ON A.Id = D.Parent_Id 
    WHERE  
        (D.Parent_Id IS NOT NULL)
)
SELECT 
    A.Id, A.TreeLevel, A.Branch, A.Name
FROM     
    Ancestor AS A
```

Execution plan on DEV:

[image]

Execution plan on QA:

[image]

Is there a way to know why plans are different on both server, and how to force QA to follow same plan as DEV?

Comment: Different data... different statistics...

Comment: @DaleK it's different plan to compute scale, not just different statistics, see the highlighted box in images

Comment: Yeah, but data and statistics are what SQL Server used to build the execution plan... so with different data and different statistics you can indeed get a completely different plan.

Comment: is there a way to tell QA server to follow what DEV is generating?

Comment: as DaleK said, the tables and their stats will be different, and this is how the execution plan is built. how many rows do you have in the Items table on each environment? assuming the indexes are the same, the statistics and the row count will create the tipping point between index scans and seeks etc ...

Comment: Also: your question text says you changed `nvarchar(max)` to `nvarchar(1024)` but the code you posted uses `varchar(1024)`. This could lead to loss of information because `varchar` data types cannot represent same range of characters as `nvarchar` data types.

Comment: @RodneyEllis QA has 5573 rows and DEV has 6541, is there any hint that I can provide along with my query to tell SQL Server how to compute scalar for [branch] because that's the only difference in both plan, DEV is re-using nested-loop with key-lookup and Index-seek, whereas QA is using Clustered Index Scan

Comment: Rather than as images, upload the execution plan xml to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by altering the index on parent_id

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Parent_Id] ON [Items] ([Parent_Id]) INCLUDE (Name) WITH DROP_EXISTING
```